# How to delete preemptible instance resources after they are preempted by Google GCE?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Preempted instances still appear in the project (I am not charged for the instances but I am charged for the disks) while they do remain listed with a TERMINATED state. As with normal instances, persistent disks that are marked for auto-delete are deleted when you delete the preemptible instance.

However, how do I delete these instances and the associated disks efficiently from command-line?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used preemptible VMs, but it looks like during VM creation you can tell GCP that you want the VM to be deleted upon termination by passing `gcloud compute instances create --instance-termination-action=DELETE ...`.

From `gcloud compute instances create --help`:

```
     --instance-termination-action=INSTANCE_TERMINATION_ACTION
        Specifies the termination action that will be taken upon VM preemption
        (--provisioning-model=SPOT or --preemptible) or automatic instance
        termination (--max-run-duration or --termination-time).
        INSTANCE_TERMINATION_ACTION must be one of:

         DELETE
            Permanently delete the VM.
         STOP
            Default. Stop the VM without preserving memory. The VM can be
            restarted later.
```

Answer (score -2):

To effectively delete preempted instances and associated disks using `gcloud` command line, use the following syntax:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format json | jq -r '.[] | select (.scheduling.preemptible == false and .status == "RUNNING") | .name+" "+ .zone' | awk '{system("gcloud compute instances delete "$1 " --zone " $2 " --delete-disks all")}'
```

This relies on [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) being installed on your OS to parse JSON output from gcloud and your zone to be configured as a default zone [in your gcloud configuration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#default-properties).

Comment: the above command deletes on demand instances since `.scheduling.preemptible == false`